Understanding the Lie derivative by multivector fields
For a vector field $X$ on a manifold there are two ways to define a Lie derivative: an algebraic one using Cartan's formula $\mathcal{L}_X \alpha = i_X d \alpha + d i_X \alpha$ and a dynamical one using the flow $\phi^X_t$,
$${\cal L}_X \alpha = \frac{d}{dt}\biggl|_{t=0} \left(\bigl(\Phi^t_X\bigr)^* T\right).$$
Given a multivector field $X$ one can define its Lie derivative by means of Cartan's formula, i.e, $\mathcal{L}_X \alpha = i_X d \alpha + d i_X \alpha$. See, for example [1].
My broad question is if the Lie derivative by a multivector means something dynamical. These are some fuzzy questions for which any help or reference would be welcomed.

In the simplest case, if $X = X_1\wedge \dotsb \wedge X_n$ and the $X_i$ span an integrable distribution, is $\alpha$ constant in some sense on the leaves of this distribution? What happens if the multivector is not integrable?

Is there a generalization of the concept of flow for a multivector that applies to this situation?

My current geometric understanding of general multivectors is that they are linear combinations of hyperplanes modulo the Plücker relations (whose geometric interpretation feels somewhat obscure to me). I would like to have a better interpretation. On question [2] on this site it is stated that they are global sections of a line bundle over the Grasmannian, some reference of this fact would be useful.


EDIT:

On [2] it is said that "is known that $Λk(V)$ is isomorphic to the space of global sections of a line bundle over the Grassmanian $Gk(V)$ of k-dimensional subspaces in $V$ - namely of the highest exterior power of the tautological bundle." I am trying to make sense of this. Let $V_k(V^*)$ be the bundle over $G_k(V^*)$ whose elements $(W,a)$ are $k$-dimensional subespaces on $V^*$ and $a$ is a volume form on $W$. A $k$-vector field $X$ can be though of as a section of this bundle: to every subspace we assign the restriction of $X$. If I understand the quotation above and it holds over the reals, $k$-vector fields are presicely algebraic sections of that bundle. Hence, a multivector is an algebraic assignment of a volume to each subespace of $V^*$. Is this true? Any reference would be great.

Also, as a follow-up partially unrelated question. Forms should be then algebraic assignments of volume to subspaces. But why would a differential geometer limit themself to algebraic sections? Has someone studied the sections of this bundle. It is posible to define integrals of submanifolds over such sections?
[1] W. M. Tulczyjew, «The Graded Lie Algebra of Multivector Fields and the Generalized Lie Derivative of Forms».
[2] მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, Cannot multivectors be classified more easily than general tensors?, URL (version: 2017-04-13): Cannot multivectors be classified more easily than general tensors?

This MO question might be of interest: https://mathoverflow.net/q/155989/11211 - In that regard, it can be shown that a 2-vector field $X=X_1\wedge X_2$ defines an integrable 2-dimensional distribution iff its Schouten-Nijenhuis bracket with itself vanishes everywhere. This also provides a characterization of when a 2-vector field is a Poisson tensor, check e.g. P. W. Michor, Remarks on the Schouten-Nijenhuis bracket, Rend. Circ. Mat. Palermo Suppl. 16 (1987), pp. 207-215, http://dml.cz/dmlcz/701423 . I don't know of a similar geometric interpretation of $p$-vector fields for $p>2$.

This does not generalize to $p$-vector fields with $p>2$. One can compute that if $X = X_1 \wedge X_2 \wedge X_3$ then $[X,X] = 0$ always.

This follows from $[X\wedge Y,Z] = X\wedge [Y,Z] \pm [X,Z]\wedge Y $ (see [1])

What about $2p$-vector fields with $p>1$ then?

They also vanish. Let $Z=X \wedge Y$ be a decomposable $p$-vector, $X$ a descomposable (p-1)-vector and $Y$  a vector. A quick calculation using the previous formula twice $[Z,Z] = \pm 2 Z \wedge [X,Y]$. If we further decompose $X = X_0 \wedge X_1$, and apply the same formula again all the terms contain either $Z \wedge X_0$, $Z \wedge X_1$, $Z \wedge Y$, which all vanish.

@LSpice. Yes, thank you

Could you say more about why you're interested in multivectors? I don't see them used much in differential geometry.

I am working on geometric field theory. Concretely on multisymplectic geometry. Mechanics (aka symplectic Hamiltonian systems) deals with particle trajectories, flows. Vector fields are linear approximations of flows.

Hamilton vector fields are dual to Hamiltonian functions.
In field theory, fields can be though as sections of an (m+k)-dimensional bundle over an m-dimensional spacetime M.
Here, it makes sense to think about observables of dimensions from 1 to n. These are called Hamiltonian forms. Dual to these forms, there are multivectors. 1 dimensional objects are vector fields that represent symmetries, whose flow preserves the system. n-vector fields, if they are decomposable define a connection whose integral sections are the fields. Here I think of the parallel transport as an analog of the flow.

Some r-vectors should represent some kind of r-dimensional generalized symmetries . I know that they are dual to conserved currents. I just  don't have a good intuition on the geometric meaning of this objects, specially the non - decomposable ones.

Sorry, I know that this is a little bit sketchy. I can be more precise, but this is the general picture
